# Mysql / MariaDb10.1 how group by after order by?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mariadb

i know there are a plenty threads similar to this but none suits my need.
I will try to explain it simpler:
I have those tables:
table TICKET with columns: TICKET_ID, TITLE
table THREAD with columns: ID, TICKET_ID, TYPE, READ

Every TICKET row have one or more rows in THREAD
THREAD>READ contains the ids (comma separated) of the staff that have read the message

I need to select all TICKET>TITLE with those conditions:
- Only one row from THREAD
- This row is chosen based on the following criterion:

1. there is no current staff id in THREAD>READ
2. current staff id is in THREAD>READ so the most recent row is taken

Local server has MariaDb 10.1, online server has Mysql 5.1 i don't know if this make difference...

Please i need help... thanks anyway, this is a great community!!!

Comment: Please provide ([Edit] your question) sample data and the desired result. Explain what difficulties you are facing.

Comment: Having multiple IDs in the same field is a very bad design (assuming it's your source table and not a view).

Comment: I don't understand the "condition" "Only one row from THREAD".

Comment: I don't understand "current".

Comment: It may help if you provide some sample data, `CREATE TABLEs`, and sample output.

Comment: Consider using a [_many-to-many mapping table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) instead of a commalist.